# localhost not opening website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

I created a blank Web App in ASP.NET on Visual Studio 2012.

When I click on Debugging using Google Chrome, Google chrome opens with text localhost on the navigation bar, but it does not open the website and keeps loading.

Comment: did you set starting page?

Comment: When i type localhost in navigation bar in browser, it keeps loading (waiting for localhost) but nothing appears..

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties page and create a virtual directory. Make sure your starting page is pointing to this. Then navigate to `http://localhost/myapp`

Comment: Make sure a port number is not being specified in IIS. You just want to go to your default landing page. All this can be configured in your project properties page.

Comment: It shows this error:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Comment: Your default page should be in the root of the project. Go to Default Documents in IIS and make sure it's added there. Try with Default.aspx

Comment: Perhaps if you showed a screenshot of your Web App properties tab - right click project in Solution Explorer and got to properties.

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/268085_488592007869767_2024509545_n.jpg

Comment: Deselect express and use custom server. You have not configured it to point to your default page.

Comment: Also try configuring your start URL

Comment: Now it says:

HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error

An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.



Most likely causes:
•This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpModules section.

Comment: What version ASPNET you using? Check your app pool settings in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is the following (running on a windows system):

Edit "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", and ensure that you have this line: "127.0.0.1  localhost"

In my case, I had "0.0.0.0 localhost" in there. 
I hope this can help.